# AJAX/JQuery error when trying to send data

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Not sure why, but I added an "error" clause to make sure the AJAX was failing...  it is.  It works correctly up to the AJAX portion, it's just not sending the data, no idea why.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#login").click(function() {

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Validating credentials...';

    var un = $("#un").val();
    var pw = $("#pw").val();

    if ( un == "" )
    {
        document.getElementById("un_error").style.visibility = 'visible';
        $("#un").focus();
    }

    if ( pw == "" )
    {
        document.getElementById("pw_error").style.visibility = 'visible';
        $("#pw").focus();
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login-parse.php',
        data: { un: un, pw: md5(pw) },
        success: function(msg) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = msg;
                    },
        error: function(xhr, status) { alert(status); }
    });

});

});
//-->
</script>
```

That's the JS code.

This is the HTML:

```
    <div id="content">
    <div id="result" class="result"></div>
    <h2>Login To Your Account</h2>
    <div class="text">
        <fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Username</legend>
                <input type="text" id="un" value="" size="20" /><span class="error" id="un_error">*</span>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Password</legend>
                <input type="password" id="pw" value="" size="30" /> <span class="error" id="pw_error">*</span>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

<?php

// Login Parser

require 'inc.common.php';

if (! isset ( $_POST['un'], $_POST['pw']) )
{
    echo '<blockquote>Invalid username/password combination.</blockquote>' . "\n";
} else {
    $un = $_POST['un'];
    $pw = md5($_POST['pw']);

    $check = $sql->result ( $sql->query ( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = \'' . $sql->escape($un) . '\' AND `user_password` = \'' . $sql->escape($pw) . '\'' ) );

    $errors = array();

    if (! strlen ( $un ) )
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid username.';

    if (! strlen ( $pw ) )
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid password.';

    if ( $check == 0 )
        $errors[] = 'Invalid username/password combination.';

    if ( count ( $errors ) > 0 )
    {
        echo '<blockquote>' . "\n",
             '  The following errors occurred with your login:' . "\n",
             '  <ul>' . "\n";
        foreach ( $errors as $enum => $error )
        {
            echo '      <li><strong>(#' . ($enum+1) . '):</strong> ' . $error . '</li>' . "\n";
        }
        echo '  </ul>' . "\n",
             '</blockquote>' . "\n";
    } else {
        setcookie ( 'ajax_un', $un, time()+60*3600 );
        setcookie ( 'ajax_pw', $pw, time()+60*3600 );

        echo '<blockquote>' . "\n",
             '  <p><strong>Success!</strong></p>' . "\n",
             '  <p>You have successfully been logged in as <strong>' . $un . '</strong>.</p>' . "\n",
             '  <p>You may now return to the <a href="index.php">index page</a>.</p>' . "\n",
             '</blockquote>' . "\n";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: And yes, jquery is called as well as a functions js file containing the md5 function.  The file "login-parse.php" is also in the same directory as the login file.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console, that's why i don't understand why it is not working

Comment: is your file "login-parse.php" in the same directory?

Comment: Sending an MD5-hashed version of a password is no more safe than sending an unhashed version over a non-encrypted connection. And you [don't need the HTML comments anymore](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/).

Comment: yep as stated above it is all in the same directory

Comment: it is initially hashed over JS so that it is not sent in plaintext, it is hashed more than once @MarcelKorpel

Comment: That doesn't matter. If one spies over the connection, one reads the hashed password and can just send that again to get access.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel yep I get what you're saying I didn't think that through; so you think scrapping AJAX for logins altogether would be the route to take?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "scrapping AJAX", but the *only* way of securing login credentials is using an SSL certificate to create an HTTPS connection.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel brain lapse...  I'll set up SSL when I actually get these files together and figure out why the AJAX isn't working...

Comment: Can you show us login-parse.php? And if you write "to make sure the AJAX was failing", then it's not strange it fails. But perhaps I misunderstand you.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I will post the login-parse.php page as well, and what I meant was that I added the "error" element so that I could be alerted if the AJAX was, in fact, failing.  Which it does.

Comment: Ah. And what is the error message?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Well the code I used to show me an error is above in the AJAX portion all it does it send an alert pop-up...  all it says is "error"

Comment: something as complicated as this is better off accompanied by a jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Jeff Hard to emulate AJAX with jsFiddle. OP: please add a third argument to `error`, i.e. `errorThrown`, and output its value to the console or an alert box. See [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Take a look at the network tab of the browser console. When the request happens you should see the request there. Does the request return with HTTP 200 or does it return an error code, etc. You can also examine the response and request directly from there including headers.

Comment: @BadWolf I am using FireBug to watch the request and view the response...  it shows me the response that should appear, but says "500 - Internal Server Error" on the login-parse.php page

Comment: That's just what it says; check the Apache error logs to see what goes wrong.

Comment: I don't know how I'd check the error logs, my site is hosted on Bihira's servers I don't think I have access to that.

Comment: @user2555004 Can you access the PHP file directly and debug it first, then use ajax once you know it's working? Also post the contents of `login-parse.php` in your question and we can check for anything obvious.

Comment: @BadWolf the login-parse.php file is the third piece of code I posted...  I'll do some debugging with PHP

Comment: @BadWolf but when I access the PHP file without the use of AJAX it works like it should...

Comment: Did you try to run it on a local instance of Apache and PHP? Then you can read error logs.

Comment: @user2555004 Take a look the firebug net tab again and expand the POST request to login-parse.php. Read through the request portion and make sure that your POST variables are being set properly. If they are, look at the response and see if there is an error message there.

Comment: @BadWolf the parameters are being set properly...  I don't understand why it gives me the error...  I checked out another page I made with essentially the same code and it doesn't give me an error...

Comment: this is the 9999999999999999999. ajax/jquery error question

Answer (score 0):

From the message "500 - Internal Server Error" in Firebug console, and the code you have posted, it seems that there is some problem in database operation.

So try to store your query a variable. Echo it and try executing same in phpMyadmin or other equivalent client you are using to access database.

If possible also post the result.